# consolidating to a single file

Tags: bibtex

I had a book published. The publisher had a LaTeX style file and we used `bibtex`, `natbib` and `multind` for those respective parts.

The publisher sent it out to a production group and the final product was setup differently than the source materials that we gave them. For example, everything was in a single file: `bibitem`s, index information etc. We used `\include` for each chapter whereas they just dumped that content into the single file.

Oddly, they also renamed each image with an explicit ordering, such as `Ch20_fig02`. They also made some errors in the file renaming process.

Finally, they converted the PDF images to large (> 30MB) eps files.

I'm just curious... was this just personal preference or are there objective reasons for making these changes. The book was about 600 pages so maybe the typesetting goes faster this way?

Comment: I don't know, if this is the personal preference of the people working for your publisher, but to me (and probably everybody else) **it doesn't make any sense to dump a document structured into several files into one file**. They probably converted all `.pdf`-graphics to `.eps`, because they are using `latex` instead of `pdflatex`, which only supports `.eps`-input. Concerning dumping the `.bbl`-file into the main document: This is done sometimes indeed, e.g. the publishers of Physical Review do that to get a standalone file, which doesn't need any more `bibtex` run (it won't change anymore).

Comment: I don't think it would be rude if you were to ask them. Presumably they feel a single, flat file is easier to manage/store/<something> than (even) a (well-structured) collection of files and folders...

Comment: This doesn't really feel answerable: too much going on.